# Responsive deisgn for featured carousel slider in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been created feature carousel slider by using jquery.featured.carousel.js file and some css.

Here is my jsfiddle [***LINK***](http://jsfiddle.net/ssqjtajj/).

When run these source code in localhost, It is need everytime refresh the page to getting responsive view when i resize the window.

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
 initSlider();

                }); 
  $( window ).resize(function() {
    initSlider();

  });

  function initSlider()
  {
    if ($( window ).width() < 1004 &&  $( window ).width() > 900)
    {
    var carousel = $("#carousel").featureCarousel({
          // include options like this:
          // (use quotes only for string values, and no trailing comma after last option)
          // option: value,
          // option: value,
        trackerIndividual:false,
        trackerSummation: false,
        autoPlay:0, 
        largeFeatureWidth :   .8,
        largeFeatureHeight:     .8,
        smallFeatureWidth:    .3,
        smallFeatureHeight:     .3,    
        topPadding:           20,    
        sidePadding:          30
        });

  }
    else if ($( window ).width() < 900 &&  $( window ).width() > 768)
    {
    var carousel = $("#carousel").featureCarousel({
          // include options like this:
          // (use quotes only for string values, and no trailing comma after last option)
          // option: value,
          // option: value,
        trackerIndividual:false,
        trackerSummation: false,
        autoPlay:0, 
        largeFeatureWidth :   .7,
        largeFeatureHeight:     .7,
        smallFeatureWidth:    .2,
        smallFeatureHeight:     .2,    
        topPadding:           40,    
        sidePadding:          30
        });

  }
    else if ($( window ).width() < 768 &&  $( window ).width() > 680)
    {
    var carousel = $("#carousel").featureCarousel({
          // include options like this:
          // (use quotes only for string values, and no trailing comma after last option)
          // option: value,
          // option: value,
        trackerIndividual:false,
        trackerSummation: false,
        autoPlay:0, 
        largeFeatureWidth :   .577,
        largeFeatureHeight:     .577,
        smallFeatureWidth:    .19999,
        smallFeatureHeight:     .19999,    
        topPadding:           40,    
        sidePadding:          30
        });

  }
    else if ($( window ).width() < 680 &&  $( window ).width() > 580)
    {
    var carousel = $("#carousel").featureCarousel({
          // include options like this:
          // (use quotes only for string values, and no trailing comma after last option)
          // option: value,
          // option: value,
        trackerIndividual:false,
        trackerSummation: false,
        autoPlay:0, 
        largeFeatureWidth :   .488,
        largeFeatureHeight:     .488,
        smallFeatureWidth:    .111,
        smallFeatureHeight:     .111,    
        topPadding:           60,    
        sidePadding:          30
        });

  }
   else if ($( window ).width() < 580 &&  $( window ).width() > 412)
    {
    var carousel = $("#carousel").featureCarousel({
          // include options like this:
          // (use quotes only for string values, and no trailing comma after last option)
          // option: value,
          // option: value,
        trackerIndividual:false,
        trackerSummation: false,
        autoPlay:0, 
        largeFeatureWidth :   .388,
        largeFeatureHeight:     .388,
        smallFeatureWidth:    .1,
        smallFeatureHeight:     .1,    
        topPadding:           70,    
        sidePadding:          30
        });

  }
    else if ($( window ).width() < 412 &&  $( window ).width() > 250)
    {

    var carousel = $("#carousel").featureCarousel({

          // include options like this:
          // (use quotes only for string values, and no trailing comma after last option)
          // option: value,
          // option: value,
        trackerIndividual:false,
        trackerSummation: false,
        autoPlay:0, 
        largeFeatureWidth :   .3,
        largeFeatureHeight:     .3,
        smallFeatureWidth:    .06,
        smallFeatureHeight:     .06,    
        topPadding:           80,    
        sidePadding:          10
        }); 

  }
    else
    {
      var carousel = $("#carousel").featureCarousel({
          // include options like this:
          // (use quotes only for string values, and no trailing comma after last option)
          // option: value,
          // option: value,
        trackerIndividual:false,
        trackerSummation: false,
        autoPlay:0, 
        largeFeatureWidth :   0,
        largeFeatureHeight:     0,
        smallFeatureWidth:    .3,
        smallFeatureHeight:     .3,    
        topPadding:           20,    
        sidePadding:          20

        });

    }
  }
    </script>
```

In the above code, I m using:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    initSlider();

  });
```

When i remove this code, again it works the same.

Note: For this carousel responsive view, I can't use css media queries.

May i know, How to set the width or how can i modify my code to get responsive view without refresh the page every time?

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you should put `setTimeout` on your `resize` function so that it doesn't call the function on every pixel when you resize the page.

Do something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
  this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
  }, 50);
});
$(window).bind('resizeEnd', function() {
  initSlider();
});
```

Also I don't think it's good idea to reinitialize the carousel settings every time it resize. There should be an option on the carousel where you can set the values without having to initialize it again. Sadly upon checking the Feature carousel it doesn't have as far as I can see.

You can make it happen I think with the use of the `css` media queries since there are classes being added on the elements e.g. `centerImage`, `imageRight` and `imageLeft`, you should be able to control it.

Comment: @sandhu yeah, like I said it can be done on `css` to fix your problem instead of re initializing it on every resize since feature carousel doesn't have an option for you to set  it on every breakpoints.

Comment: okay @Robin Carlo Catacutan: I want to know, how to avoid refresh the page when at every time resize the window?.. thanks

Comment: @sandhu I'm sorry, seems I'm wrong, the carousel lib seems weird. Even without reinitializing the carousel elements keep changing. You open to using another carousel lib?

Comment: I searching lot..but still i didn't get what i need.. thanks

Comment: @sandhu Try this http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ and checkout the Center Mode.

Comment: but i m struggling using above link's code, with my existing code... can you help me please?..

Comment: @sandhu Just do what you can, then if you ran into issues, just post it on SO then I'll be gladly to help.